# Setup local network on Mac and share it via WiFi, but with no internet connection (2022)

Tags: mac, wifi

This used to be possible, and there is a question like this on this website from 2014, but I can't find a way to do it now.

Edit:
I found the solution.

1. Go to network settings and select `Advanced...`
2. Check the box `Show legacy networks and options`
3. Click `Apply`
4. Click the WiFi icon in the menu bar
5. Hit `Create Network...`

Comment: Good solution. You should take it out of the question, however, and post the same text as an Answer. It's OK here to answer your own questions.

Comment: Post the solution as an answer